# MapKit Changing the User Location Programmatically

Tags: ios, mapkit

I am trying to make a jogging app which will track where the user ran. It will draw a line on the map where the user is running. My problem is that how to test such an app. Is there anyway I can dynamically change the user location which will fire the didUpdateUserLocation delegate method?

Comment: Device! Is there anyway to change user location like if the user is moving across the street on a device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS Simulator supports that feature in the current beta version. You can even simulate a dynamically updating location.

Comment: Thanks! that might be the solution to my problem!

Comment: Do I have to download Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5 SDK beta 3 (Snow Leopard) only since I cannot install latest iOS on my device.

Comment: @azamsharp yes, but you should also test on a real device

Comment: Oh yes of course! I just cannot install the latest iOS beta on my device. I currently have iOS 4.1 on my device!